# Parallel execution in selenium c#( not tests but a script)

Tags: c#, wpf, selenium, parallel-processing

I have a script that performs a specific operation for an ID(like login to the website and perform an action). The project is not a test project rather a simple **WPF** application. Since my script will be running on login credentials of accounts in larger amount, I want it to get executed in parallel mode(like 3,4 chrome instances executing at a single time)

Need help.

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/29367/parallel-execution-in-selenium-with-visual-studio

Comment: The link refers to a parallel test execution not for scrapping kind of thing.

Comment: You question does not say anything about scrapping.

Comment: just use one thread per driver...

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap code that does that logic - `login to the website and perform an action` in `Task.Run(() => {code})` ([see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8)).

Do not forget that you should initialize a separate Driver instance for each created task.

You can use one executable copy of ChromeDriver since all session will be limited in the launched instance.